# Relatório jasper não atualiza os dados

Tags: java, relatório, ireport, jasper-reports

Boa noite galera,
Estou com um problema um pouco frustrante.
tenho um relatório de funcionários no sistema que funciona certinho. Traz os dados tudo corretamente. Porém, quando cadastro um novo funcionário e gero o relatório novamente, ele não atualiza, fica mostrando os dados anteriores.
Alguém já passou por isso?

Abaixo, o trecho do código onde faço a chamada:

```
  public void relProdutoJASPER(List<FuncionarioEntity> p) {
    try {
        InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/br/com/portal/jasper/relFuncionario.jasper");
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource jb = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(p);
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(input, parameters, jb);
        JasperViewer js = new JasperViewer(jp, false);
        js.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        js.setTitle("Relatório de Funcionários");
        js.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cristiano, verificou se na lista de `FunctionarioEntity` que é passada por parâmetro consta o número correto de funcionários? Assim garante que o problema é apenas nesse trecho de código.

Comment: @wakim Verifiquei sim. A quantidade da lista está sempre correta, os dados também. Porém, ele mostra o relatório sempre com os dados antigos, do primeiro relatório gerado.

Comment: Esqueçam. Já resolvi. O problema não era com a chamada e nem com nada relacionado ao jasper. O problema era a forma que eu estava fazendo a consulta no JPA.